# insert data in to elastic-search from Java application

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to insert some data in to elastic search. And I tried it like this,

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
        Client client = null;
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings
                .settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name","elasticsearch")
                .build();
        try{
            client = new TransportClient(settings)
                    .addTransportAddress(new
                            InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost",9300));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter",
                    "tweet", "1")
                    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                            .startObject()
                            .field("user", "kimchy")
                            .field("postDate", new Date())
                            .field("message", "trying out Elastic Search")
                                            .endObject()
                            )
                            .execute()
                            .actionGet();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

I don't have any idea about "localtestsearch" in put method. But I dont think it causes this error.
When I tried to run this code snippet it shows me this error,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [1m]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$3.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:180)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:451)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I couldn't figure out what the error is as it says only time out.Where am I doing it wrong? Help me.

Edit

elasticsearch.yml

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
# cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
# node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
# bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
# network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
#
# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
# action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Edit2

This is the error I got when I commented out the things in config file.

```
    INFO: [Buzz] loaded [], sites []
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:182)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:310)
    at com.kodcu.main.JavaAPIMain.main(JavaAPIMain.java:123)
```

Comment: Looks like your client  is not able to locate master node. This seems to be config problem rather than code issue.

Comment: what would be the solution for that?

Comment: Update your question with server configs.

Answer (score 1):

You should comment out the following keywords on elasticsearch.yml:

```
cluster.name: your_cluster_name 
node.name: your_node_name
node.master: true
node.data: true
index.number_of_shards: number_of_shards
index.number_of_replicas: number_of_replicas
network.host: 0.0.0.0
path.conf: path_to_conf
path.data: path_to_data
```

You could also try to reach your elasticsearch server from http://localhost:9200. I recommend to install plugin head or plugin HQ in order to get better information about your elasticsearch server.

Hope this helps

> Edit

I think the typo is in the transport port. Is 9300 instead of 9200.

Comment: Yeah I am using head plug-in, I commented out every thing you said but now it shows me an another error. I will edit my question to show that error.

Comment: I just edited my answer. I think the problem is in the connect port, it should be 9300 instead of 9200

Comment: I tried it many ways, still I couldn't find a way. Now I am using elastic version 5.6. And it doesn't have yml file to edit.

Comment: Did you try using the 9300 as a connect port?